# Android Google-Driven-Push

Tags: android, push-notification

Is there a possibility to make a push service with google methods? I can only find proprietary solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, absolutely.  It's called "Google Cloud Messaging for Android."

http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html

I believe the idea is that you create a service, and that service pokes Google to send a push notification via Google Play.  Then your app receives it, and should go sync the appropriate data.

I've never used it myself, but I've been considering using it.